# Erorr: TS2339: Property 'addEmployee' does not exist on type 'EmployeesComponent'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, web

tengo el error que ven en el título y la verdad no sé cómo solucionarlo, recién estoy empezando con angular.

Lo que trato de hacer es que aparezco el formulario en el app.component.html

Este es mi código para el componente Employees

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-employees',
  templateUrl: './employees.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employees.component.css']
})
export class EmployeesComponent implements OnInit {
  addEmployee(data: any) {}
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Este es el employees.component.html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s5">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-content">
                    <form #employeeForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="addEmployee(employeeForm)" >

                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col s7">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

El error esta en la linea del form.

Ya lo importe en el app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { EmployeesComponent } from './components/employees/employees.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    EmployeesComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Y lo llame en el html de app.component, pero me muestra el error del titulo. Espero puedan ayudarme

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a stackoverflow en español. considera que aquello que pueda ser escrito como código, lo escribas como tal en tu pregunta, poner imagenes de codigo en vez de código se considera de baja calidad, y debe evitarse, porfavor te invito a que te des un paseo por el [tour] y de una vez a que leas sobre [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu archivo employeeComponent.ts agrega el método que haz definido usar en el HTML

```
  addEmployee(data: any) {}
```

Por cierto, procura cambiar las imágenes de tu código por el código en texto, sino tu pregunta será mal recibida.

Comment: Me parece bien tu respuesta, pero te recomiendo ser un poco mas especifico con nuestro amigo... recuerda que el es nuevo... a lo mejor por ejemplo no sabe lo basico, como por ejemplo que el html en angular se puede conectar directamente con su componente.ts... tal vez por eso no tenia agregado su método, que tal si le das una respuesta un poco mas elaborada y explicativa?